# What does this Bruce Schneier fact mean?

Tags: cryptography

I came across a website called [Bruce Schneier Facts](https://www.schneierfacts.com/), a parody along the lines of Chuck Norris facts, and saw the following fact:

> [Schneier knows if Reiser did it.](https://www.schneierfacts.com/facts/894)

What does it mean?

Comment: Almost certainly it's referring to Hans Reiser, an OSS software developer who murdered his wife in 2006.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Reiser  (He did it, and later lead police to where her body was buried)

Comment: How is this on-topic for this site?

Comment: @Gaius. I had a preface in my question stating that it was a silly question, but that seems to have been edited away. Among all other stackexchange sites, this site seemed like it would be most familiar with Bruce Schneier and I couldn't help it.

Comment: This fact is probably old and refers to the time when Reiser claimed to be innocent and investigation was slow because there was no body and no crime scene. Nowadays, you don't need to be Bruce Schneier nor Chuck Norris to know it, since Hans Reiser not only plead guilty in his criminal trial, but later in a civil lawsuit brought against him by his family, he even argued publicly in court that he murdered his wife to protect their children and thus shouldn't have to pay damages.

Comment: @Gaius it isn't about security once you know what the Reiser reference means. Since so many of the other facts on the site are about security in some way, it is reasonable to assume that the fact is relevant to security (even though the answer is that it is not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by [@SteveSether](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/56022/steve-sether) in their [comment](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/219519/what-does-this-bruce-schneier-fact-mean#comment445601_219519).

> Almost certainly it's referring to Hans Reiser, an OSS software developer who murdered his wife in 2006. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hans_Reiser (He did it, and later lead police to where her body was buried).